# how to open activity in diffrent tab from one tab?

Tags: android, tabs

1. This is my class:

   ```
   public class DumyDisplay extends TabGroupActivity
   ```
2. I am calling new activity which is part of other tab:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent(DumyDisplay.this,SmsActivity.class);
   i.putExtra(BODY_SMS, dataInboxBody);
   startChildActivity("DumyDisplay", i);
   ```

The problem is that it's opening in the same tab but I want to open it in different tab.

Answer (score 0):

try this to call a new Activity of another Tab,

```
Intent i= new Intent(getParent(), SmsActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("SmsActivity", i);
```